# Cent OS. Removed yum packages with apt-get. Server at work is down

Tags: mysql, apt, yum, aptitude

I ran:

```
 sudo apt-get --fix-broken install
```

and ended up removing:

```
MySQL-client (5.0.92-0.glibc23)
MySQL-server (5.0.92-0.glibc23)
bandmin (1.6.1-1_newinit)
exim (4.69-30_cpanel_maildir)
mdadm (2.6.9-3.el5)
redhat-lsb (4.0-2.1.4.el5)
redhat-lsb.32bit (4.0-2.1.4.el5)
sendmail-cf (8.13.8-8.el5)
sendmail-devel (8.13.8-8.el5)
sendmail-devel.32bit (8.13.8-8.el5)
```

I am very unpopular at work at the moment.

trying to install mysql client I get:

```
No package mysql-client available.
```

What gives :) ? should I add a list of new repositories?

How about mysql-data is it gone :) ! ?

Comment: You still have `yum` installed? If yes please post the output of `yum search mysql`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still have `yum` installed? If yes please post the output of `yum search mysql` or just try `yum install mysql mysql-server`